# Run ftp.exe with a command line argument

Tags: windows, ftp

I was trying to run the following script in command line  in windows xp but I couldn't make it :

```
C:\..\ftp  -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open someweb.com
username
password
pwd
bye
```

the following runs ok:

```
ftp>@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open someweb.com
username
password
pwd
bye
```

but I am trying to achieve it with command line. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do it directly on the command line, but you can use the command line to build a file that you can send as input to `ftp`:

```
C:\>echo open someweb.com >input
C:\>echo next ftp commmand >>input
C:\>echo another ftp commmand >>input
C:\>ftp -i <input
```